# CSS Flex: Horizontal Centering and stacking using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create horizontally centered divs that stack on top of each other using a combination of justify-content and flex-direction.

Problem:
Children divs are stacked on top of each other, but are no longer horizontally centered, but vertically centered instead.

```
    .parent {
      position: fixed;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center; // children becomes vertically centered
      flex-direction: column; // stacking 
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: .parent * { display: block; } don't work ?

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: How about a pen or fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

The `flex-direction` property changes the main axis of a given container - thus, given that you changed the direction to `column`, you would now want to use `align-items` versus `justify-content`:

```
.foo {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

You can read more about `flex-direction` [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), and [here's a Codepen](http://codepen.io/andRyanMiller/pen/MwbbZp) demonstrating the usage of the new property.